# What is the purpose of approximating solutions to equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

Many times one wants to approximate solutions to equations, particularly when the equation in question has no closed form. For example: $x^5 - x + 1 = 0$. The approximate solution to this, which one can get by using Newton's method, is $-1.167303978$.

However, regardless of how accurate we make our solution, there will still be infinitely many numbers in between our approximation and the actual solution. In this sense, $-1.167303978$ is no better an approximation than $-500$.

From the standpoint of *pure* mathematics, this is entirely unsatisfying. What is the point then?

Comment: Try the standpoint of engineering and then ask the question

Comment: Well, as the real numbers are (naturally?) a metric space, people who believe $-1.167$ is a better approximation than $-500$ do have a *fairly* strong case...

Comment: *Of course* it's a better approximation than $-500$: it's **closer**. The cardinality of the gap has nothing to do with it. The topology (in this case, the metric) is what matters.

Comment: @symplectomorphic You're right: I technically miswrote. Essentially, what I'm trying to say is not that it isn't a better approximation, but that since there's still infinitely many numbers closer to it (ie. better approximations) what is its significance?  In what sense can we say that it is a "solution"? Why do pure mathematicians even care about the notion of approximation, at least in this particular context (I'm sure in other contexts it is useful).

Answer (score 4):

The point is that you 
sometimes have to be satisfied
with an approximate answer
when there is no 
exact analytic answer.

Also,
if you can compute
a very accurate answer,
this can suggest other
mathematical results.
A useful search term might be
"experimental mathematics".

Somehow,
I find the tone of your question
disturbing,
as if you lack
some understanding
of why mathematics is done.
I may be wrong.

Comment: To address your last sentence: when I think of mathematics, I think of $p \implies q$. $p \lor \lnot \ p $. Logic. Rigour. Perhaps this is "philosophically" incorrect, or naive. Regardless, I appreciate your input. +1

Answer (score 4):

> CITATION : However, regardless of how accurate we make our solution, there will still be infinitely many numbers in between our approximation and the actual solution. In this sense, −1.167303978 is no better an approximation than −500.

A main concern of Mathematicians is to define the terms they are using.

The point here is that your definition of approximation seems to refer to the "numbers in between our approximation and the actual solution". This is a strange idea that I saw nowhere. In this sense any number would be the appoximate of any other number : This is a non-sens for a useful definition.

Usually the definition refers to the error, i.e. the difference between our approximation and the actual solution, with some variants : absolute, relative, squared, etc.

The absolute error is less than 0.00000001 for the approximate −1.167303978 while the absolute error is more than 499 for the "approximate" -500. It is clear that the first is much better than the second.

Comment: +1 I think this answer gets at least close to the heart of the matter.